# Asyncronously add history to existing HighStock chart

Tags: asynchronous, highcharts

I'm scripting a web page that displays a HighStock chart of data from ThingSpeak.  It limits data calls to 8000 points, so I need to make several calls to load the entire data set.  I plan to show the chart when the latest data comes in, and then add earlier data.  My first attempt using addPoint() expands the navigator back to 1970, but does not add the data.  Is there a problem adding data with dates earlier than the current data?  How should I script this?

Here's how I call the addPoint() method:

```
dynamicChart.series[fieldList[fieldIndex].series]
          .addPoint(fieldList[fieldIndex].data,false);
```

and the Array[] that I send it:

```
fieldList: Array[3]
  0: Object
    data: Array[8000]
      0: Array[2]
          0: 1371821816000
          1: 36.79
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array[0]
      1: Array[2]
          0: 1371821836000
          1: 36.75
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array[0]
      2: Array[2]
      3: Array[2]
      4: Array[2]
```

I tried increasing the turboThreshold to 10000, but it didn't help.

Then I replaced the add points() line with this:

```
dynamicChart.series[fieldList[fieldIndex].series].addPoint({},false);
```

...and got the same result.  What's going on here?  Whats wrong with my data object?

Comment: There is no problem with displaying data before current data. Make sure your points have numbers as values and turboThreshold is set to high enough if you are using objects as points. Also, make jsFiddle example with that issue.

Comment: please see the detail I added to the question above.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to see more code - as I said before, play a while with jsFiddle, and reproduce there issue.

Comment: @Paweł Fus: I may have the answer.  Can addPoint() add an array of 8000 [x,y] points in one call as I am attempting, or can it only add a single [x,y] point?

Comment: Only one point. To set array of points use [setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData()) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addPoints() method only adds a single point.

My solution was to push the new points into the origional array, sort it, and then use setData() to update the series:

```
for (var h=0; h<data.feeds.length; h++)  // iterate through each feed (data point)
{
  // if a numerical value exists add it
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(v))) { fieldList[fieldIndex].data.push(p); }
}

fieldList[fieldIndex].data.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]});
dynamicChart.series[fieldList[fieldIndex].series].setData(fieldList[fieldIndex].data,false);
```

Sorting was important, if the order is not increasing, the new data will not be displayed.